# MySQL Before Trigger Performance Issue

Tags: mysql, performance, triggers

I need to load data to a MYSQL table using LOAD data. While loading, I need to set a data flag column to appropriate value based on certain conditions. The data insertion can happen from different scripts and I thought of using BEFORE INSERT trigger so as to centralize the process. Now the problem is the INSERT process takes lot of time. As a sample, when I used SOURCE command from command line with a file of 500 000 records for putting test data, a block 
of 550 records takes around 19 sec for insertion starting on a blank table. When I used LOAD data with around 2300 records (this is ideal insertions that can happen on regular basis,unless previous insertions fail and data to be inserted accumulates), it took around 90 sec to complete.

I would like to know:

1. If I can anyway improve the performance of this trigger as it is or do the triggers in general are slow?
2. If I shift the same logic to outside trigger to regular SQL in processing will the performance improve.(Trigger vs regular SQL). Sorry, for some reasons I could not test this scenario.Also since I have many scripts from where data insertions can happen I wanted to avoid do in this.

My trigger logic is

```
CREATE TRIGGER `mydb`.`flag_data` BEFORE INSERT ON `mydb`.`mytable`

FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    DECLARE threshold_val FLOAT;
    DECLARE time_upper_limit_1 FLOAT;
    DECLARE time_upper_limit_2 FLOAT;
    SET threshold_val = 400;
    SET time_upper_limit_1 = 4000;
    SET time_upper_limit_2 = 8000;

    SET new.data_flag=(SELECT CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 0 THEN 2 ELSE (SELECT CASE WHEN new.rf >@threshold_val THEN 5 WHEN new.rf < 0 THEN 5 ELSE (SELECT CASE WHEN MINUTE( new.rec_time) Mod 15 <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE new.data_flag END) END) END FROM vw_active_stn_list WHERE stn_id=new.stn_id);

    IF (new.data_flag = 0) THEN
        IF (new.rmode = 'H') THEN
            SET new.data_flag=(SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*)>0 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END FROM vw_mf_list WHERE stn_id=new.stn_id);
        ELSEIF (new.rmode = 'F') THEN
            SET new.data_flag=(SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 4 ELSE (SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,new.rec_time,Now()))=1 THEN 1 WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,new.rec_time,Now()) NOT BETWEEN 0 AND @time_upper_limit_1 THEN 1  ELSE 0 END ) END from stn_mf WHERE ((new.rec_time BETWEEN mf_start_time AND mf_end_time) OR (mf_start_time <= new.rec_time AND mf_end_time IS NULL)) AND stn_id=new.stn_id AND (stn_type='X' OR stn_type='Y'));
        ELSEIF (new.rmode = 'S' OR new.rmode = 'M') THEN
            SET new.data_flag=(SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 4 ELSE (SELECT CASE WHEN ISNULL(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,new.rec_time,Now()))=1 THEN 1 WHEN TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,new.rec_time,Now()) NOT BETWEEN 0 AND @time_upper_limit_2 THEN 1  ELSE 0 END ) END from stn_mf WHERE ((new.rec_time BETWEEN mf_start_time AND mf_end_time) OR (mf_start_time <= new.rec_time AND mf_end_time IS NULL)) AND stn_id=new.stn_id AND (stn_type='X' OR stn_type='Y'));
        END IF;
    END IF;
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Triggers are slower for bulk loads. In your case, it would be beneficial to switch to standard SQL instead of triggers.

Triggers could be useful if you have fewer and less frequent inserts.